# What's the current impl. of NuGet stuff in .csproj?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, csproj, nuget-package-restore

I have a few solutions that started out in VS2008 or VS2010 or something like that. They contain some stuff that I think relate to NuGet package restore and including certain MS NuGet packages in the build process.

But this looks different in different projects, while I see no reason for any differences, and a new VS2017 project contains yet another different version.

So, what could I safely do to get my old projects up to date in this regard - what should it look like now, in VS2017?

Both old solutions contain a solution-level subfolder ".nuget" with three files: `NuGet.Config`, `NuGet.exe` and `NuGet.targets`.

The old `.csproj` files contain these "versions" of NuGet stuff:

Proj1:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

Proj2 (additional conditions):

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

Proj3 (doesn't import nuget.targets):

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

A new VS2017 web application project (doesn't import nuget.targets or Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21, different `<Error Condition.../>` tags):

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
  <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
</Target>
```

I would like to have the same setup for all these old projects (unless there would be specific reasons to differ), and I want the setup to be up to date with the tools and environment as per VS2017.

I have automatic package restore enabled and want to keep it that way.

Note: All four projects seem to build and run successfully. Proj2 and Proj3 are unit test projects. Proj1 is really two projects that are identical in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the current impl. of NuGet stuff in .csproj?

To resolve this question, you can follow below steps:

1. Close Visual Studio to avoid file potential file locks and conflicts.
2. If using TFS: Remove `nuget.exe` and `nuget.targets` from the solution's `.nuget` folder and remove those files from the solution workspace. Retain `nuget.config` with the disableSourceControlIntegration setting as explained in [Omitting packages with Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control#omitting-packages-with-team-foundation-version-control).
3. If **not** using TFS:  Remove the `.nuget` folder from the solution and the solution workspace.
4. Edit each project file in the solution, **remove** the `<RestorePackages>` element, and remove any references to the nuget.targets file.

   ```
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
   ```

   **And**

   ```
   <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />

   <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">  
     <PropertyGroup>    
     <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>  
     </PropertyGroup>  
     <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
   </Target>
   ```

Note: Retain `<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build...`

For some details, please refer to:

[Nuget: Switching from "Enable Package Restore" to "Automatic Package Restore"](https://chrismay.org/2015/01/07/nuget-switching-from-enable-package-restore-to-automatic-package-restore/).

Comment: Thanks! Will read the ref. In my .lsn file I find below section. Should I remove it?  

    `Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{9CD7B238-A979-4D2C-9E09-586BBF9C4162}"
        ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
            .nuget\NuGet.Config = .nuget\NuGet.Config
            .nuget\NuGet.exe = .nuget\NuGet.exe
            .nuget\NuGet.targets = .nuget\NuGet.targets
        EndProjectSection
    EndProject`

Comment: I removed it (the section above, from .sln file). Seems to work.

Comment: I've found that there's a new .csproj format with a tag `PackageReference`, but it seems that it doesn't support legacy .Net Framework projects. Is this still correct or has it been fixed? And how would I do the conversion? Also, would it help to upgrade to target .Net Framework 4.7.1 (which apparently now includes full .Net Standard 2.0)?

Comment: That new .csproj format is still support legacy .Net Framework projects, you can convert it to new .csproj:http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/, if you have any project with target framework .Net Standard 2.0, you can upgrade to target framework 4.7.1.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your comment. I already read the article you linked, and it seems to say that it won't work for non-Core ASP.NET apps (like mine). But the article is almost a year old, so I thought perhaps the situation has changed since?